# Create bidiagonal matrix in Julia with comprehension

Tags: julia

How to recreate this bidiagonal matrix in julia with a comprehension ?

```
  1   0   0
 -1   1   0
  0  -1   1
  0   0  -1
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use a comprehension?

Comment: Well if there is a better way i will be glad to know it. I just found the bidiagonal function but how to make this matrix dims(100,100) without a function or a comprehension.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a comprehension creates a dense array, and it can be non-square:

```
julia> M = 4; N = 3;
       [i==j ? 1 : i==j+1 ? -1 : 0 for i = 1:M, j=1:N]
4x3 Array{Int64,2}:
  1   0   0
 -1   1   0
  0  -1   1
  0   0  -1
```

Or you can use `Bidiagonal` for a square matrix:

```
julia> M = 4;
       Bidiagonal(ones(Int, M), -ones(Int, M-1), false) # false means that it's not an upper-diagonal
4x4 Bidiagonal{Int64}:
  1   0   0  0
 -1   1   0  0
  0  -1   1  0
  0   0  -1  1
```

The latter has some specialized linear algebra methods that may make it more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you are saying that Bidiagonal() can only be a square matrix ? So, if i want a 4x3 a comprehension is the way to go ?

Answer (score 3):

I know it is a little late now but I have a faster way, if you need to go really large. For your example I wrote a function:

```
    function Bi_diag(M,N,d1,d2)
    A = zeros(M,N);
    A[1:M+1:end] = d1;
    A[2:M+1:end] = d2;
    return A
    end
```

This is much faster than the example given above if you need to make a large matrix for your small example: M = 4, N = 3, d1 = 1, d2 = -1. In general using A[1:M+1:end] = d is a fast way to fill the main diagonal. To fill a lower diagonal you start from the first element of the lower diagonal (in your example 2) and to fill an upper diagonal you go to M+diag where diag is the upper diagonal number you want to fill. So to fill the first diagonal above the main diagonal in your small example it would be A[M+1:M+1:end] = d3. 
Also using my function leaves the possibility of putting in values that are not all the same (filling the diagonal with a variety of numbers instead of all the same number).